# Pass sudo password prompt to stdout of spawned process in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, command-line-interface, sudo, pty

I have built a GUI with Node.js that allows a user to run custom binaries, designed for CLI. These binaries are spawned with `child_process` module. A user is able to write to `stdin` and read from `stdout` of those child processes.

Yet, when a binary uses `sudo` command, a password prompt bypass `stdout` and is headed for (pseudo-)terminal device, therefore I can't catch it programmatically and ask user for a password with a fancy GUI notification. I am aware, that `-S` argument allows `sudo` to expect the password from the standard input, yet I have no control over scripts that are run by a user.

I have found out that the stream object that represents `stdin` or `stdout` of a process may have `isTTY` property that indicates that this process is run in TTY context. I have tried to pass streams created with `TTY` module to `stdio` argument of `child_process.spawn` method without any luck.

I tried to use `pty.js` project (https://github.com/chjj/pty.js/) that actually solves the problem, but for some reasons I can't rely on 3rd party libraries. I try to figure out the way `pty.js` redirects `sudo` prompts to `stdin`, and it seems they use custom C code to emulate PTY (https://github.com/chjj/pty.js/blob/master/src/unix/pty.cc). I am concerned with a comment in one of source files, that states that ‘*<...> with vanilla node, it's impossible to spawn a child process that has the stdin and stdout fd's be isatty <...>*’. Is that true?

Right now I use a workaround that requires user to elevate privileges to my GUI process so it can spawn children that may use sudo, but I'm not satisfied with this hack. According to manual (http://linux.die.net/man/8/sudo), there is a way to specify helper program to handle password prompt by setting `SUDO_ASKPASS` environment variable, but I wasn't able to find an example of such an application.

So I'd like to know if there is a common practice to overcome my problem or should I give up and just keep on with getting root privileges preliminary.

Comment: The problem with passing `sudo`'s passwd prompt to its spawned process' `stdout` is that when `sudo` prompts for a passwd, I believe that the sub-shell (corresponding to its cmd line arguments) is not spawned yet. Am I understanding you well ?

Comment: If I may suggest this: when invoking `sudo <cmd>` and if in a Bourne-like shell, do: `sudo cmd -- 1> sudo-stdout.log`. Would then querying `sudo-stdout.log` be good enough for you ? If so you can make that more sophisticated w/ time-stamps and perhaps needed PIDs, but the gist is there.

Comment: Cbhihe, as far as I understand, no sub-shell is spawned for child processes as there is no top-level shell to fork from. The program is based on [Electron](http://electron.atom.io/), that runs as a GUI application (as an .app package for Mac OS to be more exact), and user is not supposed to run it from command line. So, no shell interface is available.

Comment: ok. my bad. Yr environment was not quite clear to me.