# Redirect _sudo_ 's PID, stderr and stdout to file

Tags: bash, shell, sudo, io-redirection

***How can `_user_` redirect `PID` as well as `stdout` and `stderr` of `sudo` (and not of the sub-shell it spawns) to file ?***

I.e. the `sudo` passwd request (`[sudo] password for _user_: _`) and any error normally sent to the current shell's `stdout` and `stderr` by `sudo` should be redirected to any appropriate file `/path/foobar`, in the spirit of:
 `{sudo-process} &> >(tee /path/foobar > /dev/null)` or
 `{sudo-process} 2>&1 | tee /path/foobar &>/dev/null)`
as far as `stdout` and `stderr` are concerned. In my use case, `PID` is also needed to make unattended killing of the `sudo` process possible from an external script with appropriate privis.

By "current shell", I mean the shell in which the `sudo` process lives.
The farthest I got to is a possible `askpass` program (see option `-A` in [man 8 sudo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36756398/pass-sudo-password-prompt-to-stdout-of-spawned-process-in-node-js)) and the possibility to use `plugins` which may or may not be relevant. I have no experience at all with that. *Can you help ?*

---

Note: I am ***NOT looking*** at redirecting output from a shell spawned by `sudo` to file. As in:
`$ sudo cmd &> /path/foobar` or `$ sudo sh -c 'cmd &> /path/foobar'`
depending on whether `/path/foobar` is a file with appropriate write permission, i.e. accessible to `cmd`'s redirection of `stdout`and `stderr`. This is not the issue.

***EDIT:***
@JohnKugelman suggests running `sudo -n` which causes `sudo` to emit an error message to `stderr` and to die, in case a passwd is needed. That takes care of:
- redirecting `stdout`, since there is none anymore.
- the need to store `sudo`'s PID, since the process dies on its own.

The main issue remains: ***how to redirect `sudo`'s `stderr` to file ?***

Comment: To what end? Perhaps `sudo -n` would be better: "The `-n` option prevents sudo from prompting the user for a password. If a password is required for the command to run, sudo will display an error message and exit." -- [sudo(8)](http://linux.die.net/man/8/sudo)

Comment: @JohnKugelman: Thanks. I was reading on that option exactly this instant. That takes care of `sudo`'s PID, in that it needs not be stored anymore. However the main issue remains: *redirecting `stderr` of `sudo` process to file, **unattended**.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To redirect sudo's stderr to file:

```
sudo -n cmd -- &> /path/of/the/file
```

Comment: Thank you, MarcoS. :-)))